# Is the functional equation for $\zeta (s) \left(1-\frac{1}{3^{s-1}}\right)$ known?

Tags: special-functions, functional-equations, riemann-zeta

It says in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) that Hardy gave a simple proof of the functional equation for:

$$\eta(s)=\zeta (s) \left(1-\frac{1}{2^{s-1}}\right)$$

and that it is:

$$\eta(-s) = 2 \frac{1-2^{-s-1}}{1-2^{-s}} \pi^{-s-1} s \sin\left({\pi s \over 2}\right) \Gamma(s)\eta(s+1)$$

Trying to generalize this to the von Mangoldt function, I am wondering as a first step if the functional equation for:

$$\zeta (s) \left(1-\frac{1}{3^{s-1}}\right)$$

is known?

Comment: Yes, just change $2^{-s}$ to $3^{-s}$ (and $2^{-s-1}$ to $3^{-s-1}$) in the func. equations for $\eta$.

Comment: @GrigoryM I don't see how that could work. I entered those changes as a computation in mathematica and could not get the right answer:

s = 2 + 3 I;
N[Zeta[-s]*(1 - 1/2^(-s - 1))]
N[2*(1 - 2^(-s - 1))/(1 - 2^(-s))*Pi^(-s - 1)*s*Sin[Pi*s/2]*Gamma[s]*
  Zeta[s + 1]*(1 - 1/2^(1 + s - 1))]

Comment: Anyways you were almost right, as shown in the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume $a$ is a real number such that $a^{s-1}\neq1$. If you set
$$
z(s)=\zeta (s) \left(1-\frac{1}{a^{s-1}}\right),
$$ then, using the functional equation for $\zeta$, you obtain
$$
\begin{align}
z(1-s)&=\zeta (1-s) \left(1-\frac{1}{a^{-s}}\right)\\\\
&=2\frac{\Gamma(s)}{(2\pi)^s} \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}s\right)  \zeta(s)\times \left(1-\frac{1}{a^{-s}}\right)\\\\
&=2\frac{\Gamma(s)}{(2\pi)^s} \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}s\right) \frac{1-a^s}{1-\frac{1}{a^{s-1}}} \times \zeta(s)\times \left(1-\frac{1}{a^{s-1}}\right)\\\\
&=-2a^s\frac{\Gamma(s)}{(2\pi)^s} \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}s\right) \frac{1-a^{-s}}{1-a^{1-s}} \times z(s)\\\\
\end{align}
$$ or, with $s \to s+1$,

> $$
> \color{blue}{z(-s)}=2\:\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^{s+1}\frac{1-a^{-s-1}}{1-a^{-s}}\pi^{-s-1}s\sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\Gamma(s) \:\color{blue}{z(s+1)}.
> $$

Comment: Sir, this is an amazing answer! Now I will see how it works with:
$$\lim\limits_{s \rightarrow a+bi} \zeta(s)\sum\limits_{d|n} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^{(s-1)}}$$

Comment: @MatsGranvik Thanks. Observe that  this is equivalent to the classic functional equation for $\zeta$ :)

Comment: Is it possible to symmetrize that functional equation in your answer? Like the Riemann Xi function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_Xi_function